# AWS CLI Windows Powershell command error

Tags: aws-cli

I am running following `AWS CLI` command on `Windows powershell`. It is reporting that I have not specified `ParameterValue` for `ParameterKey` `KeyName` but I have. Why is this command isn't working?

```
PS C:\Users\Manu> aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name vpn --template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsinaction/chapter5/vpn-cloudformation.json --para
meters ParameterKey=KeyName, ParameterValue=mykey ParameterKey=VPC, ParameterValue=$VpcId ParameterKey=Subnet, ParameterValue=$SubnetId ParameterKey=IPSecShar
edSecret, ParameterValue=$SharedSecret ParameterKey=VPNUser, ParameterValue=vpn ParameterKey=VPNPassword, ParameterValue=$Password

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: ParameterValue for ParameterKey KeyName is required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell is having difficulty parsing that comma and thereby loses the ParameterValue afterwards. Wrap the complete section after *--parameter* in double-quotes, so that it would be able to resolve it.

I would still suggest you to use [AWS Tools for Powershell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) which is far more easier to deal all these.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had to use double quotes for each `parameterKey` parameterValue` pair:  `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name vpn --template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsinaction/chapter5/vpn-cloudformation.json --para
meters "ParameterKey=KeyName, ParameterValue=mykey" "ParameterKey=VPC, ParameterValue=$VpcId" "ParameterKey=Subnet, ParameterValue=$SubnetId" "ParameterKey=IPSecShar
edSecret, ParameterValue=$SharedSecret" "ParameterKey=VPNUser, ParameterValue=vpn" "ParameterKey=VPNPassword, ParameterValue=$Password`"